# Vb.Net not connected with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, adodb

General.vb file:

Need to know why db is not connected? Is there any problem with Connection String?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module General
    Public conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Public sql As String
    Public rs, rss As New ADODB.Recordset
    Public admission_no As Integer
    Public view_student As Boolean = False
    Public visitor_name, vdate, sname, comp, dat, stat
    Public visitor As Boolean = False
    Public complaint As Boolean = False
    Public abc As String
    Public Function OpenDB()
        Try


            If conn.State = 1 Then conn.Close()
            conn.Open("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Users\IJAJ\Documents\hostel1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;")
            Return (0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Database is not connected ..... Please Check Your Network Connection", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End
        End Try
    End Function
End Module
```

Connection String Tried:

```
conn.Open("Provider=sqloledb;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=hostel1;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSIP;")
```

but not working... still db not connected.

Comment: Connection String Tried conn.Open("Provider=sqloledb;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=hostel1;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSIP;") but not working... still db not connected.

Comment: what's the actual real exception being generated? You are swallowing the exception and replacing it with your arbitrary message. Set a breakpoint and report the real message. This is a _basic_ debugging task which really you should have done before even posting a question. Otherwise you're just guessing. You're assuming it's related to the connection string, but there could be other issues. The exception details will give you a clue.